# Specifying the form of names for categories generated by patsy/statsmodels 'C'

Tags: categorical-data, python

By default, Patsy's `C` seems to generate categories with names of the form

```
C(color, Treatment('White'))[T.Green]
```

at least when used in a formula provided to `statsmodels` `old`. Is there a way to specify that `C` generate less verbose category names, e.g., of the form

```
colorGreen
```

or even simply

```
Green
```

Comment: That question is on Stack Overflow; this question seems more suited to that site for the same reasons: this centres on use of particular software. If there is a statistical question at the heart of it, please make it more obvious.

Comment: @NickCox: Should be moved then.

Comment: I've voted to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue for this open. Please discuss alternatives there.

https://github.com/pydata/patsy/issues/19

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but for those searching this in 2021.

If you're prepared todo a bit of wrangling, you can take apart the statsmodel `Summary` object (returned when calling `summary()` on a fitted model), convert it to a DataFrame, and format it from there.

The `Summary` object has a `tables` attribute. The first is the result of the fit, the second is the coefficents table. The tables have an `as_html()` method that you can pass to the pandas `read_html()` method.

```py
df = pd.read_html(your_fitted_model.summary().tables[1].as_html(), header=0)[0]
```

From there you can strip out the patsy formatting via regular string and dataframe methods.